# Find out which database consumes how much memory

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, space

I am working with MSSQL Server. I want to find out which of my databases in the server takes how much memory/space.
A friend of mine told me that there is a "task" to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and this [article](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/08/05/sql-server-knowing-which-database-is-consuming-my-memory/) seems to be the solution.

First,list the Number of pages in the buffer pool by database and page type :

```
SELECT DB_NAME(database_id),
page_type,
COUNT(page_id) AS number_pages
FROM sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors
WHERE database_id! = 32767
GROUP BY database_id, page_type
ORDER BY number_pages DESC
```

Then, list the number of pages in the buffer pool by database

```
SELECT DB_NAME(database_id),
COUNT(page_id) AS number_pages
FROM sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors
WHERE database_id! =32767
GROUP BY database_id
ORDER BY database_id
```

You can see from the output, you will be able to see the amount of data pages and index pages that are loaded into your SQL Server memory.

```
Try to list the number of pages in the buffer pool by page type
SELECT page_type, COUNT(page_id) AS number_pages
FROM sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors
GROUP BY page_type
ORDER BY number_pages DESC
GO
```

Then list the number of dirty pages in the buffer pool

```
SELECT COUNT(page_id) AS number_pages
FROM sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors
WHERE is_modified = 1
```

You will display the dirty pages that are in memory and are yet to be flushed out.